# Updating data from the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have this table that receive from the server: (with ajax):

```
   $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $('#MyTable tbody').append("<tr>"d
             +"<td>" +data[i].A+ "</td><td>" 
             +data[i].B
             +"</td><td><input type='text' value='"
             +data[i].C+"'/></td><td><input type='text' value='"
             + data[i].D+"'/></td>"
             + "</tr>");
        });
```

C and D are edit text, that the user can change them. after the changing by the user, the data will sent to the server.

I have a problem in changing only D column. when changing only D column, in "`newData`" (from this line of code: "`var newData = getUserData();`"), I get "...{..."C":"x"}..." and I expected to get "...{..."D":"x"}...". why?
("x" is an exp of data in D column).
(the other options working well).

```
function getUserData()
{
    var newData = new Array();
    $.each($('#MyTable tbody tr'),function(key,val){
         var inputF = $(this).find("input[type=text].changed");   
        var fileldValues = {};
        fileldValues['c'] = $(inputF[0]).val();
        fileldValues['d'] = $(inputF[1]).val();
        fileldValues['a'] = $($(this).children()[0]).text();
        fileldValues['b'] = $($(this).children()[1]).text();
        newData.push(fileldValues);
    });
    return JSON.stringify(newData);
}

function saveNewData(){

var newData = getUserData();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "save",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 
    newData: newData},
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(data) {
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}); 
}
```

also I am using this event:

```
$('#MyTable input[type=text]').on('change',function() {
     $(this).addClass('changed');
})
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are taking the .changed element without checking if it is C or D.
For example. lets take all possible scenarios:
 1. You change only C: - now input C has class .changed therefore executing "fileldValues['c'] = $(inputF[0]).val();" gives to 'c' the correct value. 
 2. You change both - then both fields have the class .changed therefore both calls are working again
 3. The problem - changing only D - this will mean that the CInput field will not have class .changed but the D Field will. Therefore when you get it with the selector, now inputF[0] is actually field D because it is the only field with class changed. Thats why the value in D is written in the C fieldValue.

To fix that just create a way to know which one was changed so that you assign the changed value to the correct fieldValue.

There are many approaches you can take to start identifying C and D. Personally I would choose to add them each a different Additional class. Because you have the tr object and you use find you will recieve only the objects within that element that meet the selector, so adding a "C" class to the C input and a "D" class to the D Input will give you a way to know which is which (remember an element can have many classes so its not a problem that you append .changed later) in your code this will look like:
1. When creating the table:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $('#MyTable tbody').append("<tr>"d
         +"<td>" +data[i].A+ "</td><td>" 
         +data[i].B
         +"</td><td><input type='text' class='C' value='"
         +data[i].C+"'/></td><td><input type='text' class='D' value='"
         + data[i].D+"'/></td>"
         + "</tr>");
    });
```

Then in your getUserData function, you will get those items first and then checked if they are changed (have class changed):

```
function getUserData()
{
    var newData = new Array();
    $.each($('#MyTable tbody tr'),function(key,val){              
        var inputC = $(this).find(".C");
        var inputD = $(this).find(".D");
        var fileldValues = {};
        fileldValues['c'] = $(inputC).val();
        fileldValues['d'] = $(inputD).val();
        fileldValues['a'] = $($(this).children()[0]).text();
        fileldValues['b'] = $($(this).children()[1]).text();
        newData.push(fileldValues);
    });
    return JSON.stringify(newData);
}
```

as you are always using their values I am not sure why are you specifically checking if there were any changes ? If you want to send only the changed value then you modify this by:

```
function getUserData()
{
    var newData = new Array();
    $.each($('#MyTable tbody tr'),function(key,val){ 
        var fileldValues = {};

        var inputC = $(this).find(".C");
        if ($(inputC).hasClass("changed")) { 
           fileldValues['c'] = $(inputC).val();
        }
        var inputD = $(this).find(".D");
        if ($(inputD).hasClass("changed")) { 
           fileldValues['d'] = $(inputD).val();
        }

        fileldValues['a'] = $($(this).children()[0]).text();
        fileldValues['b'] = $($(this).children()[1]).text();
        newData.push(fileldValues);
    });
    return JSON.stringify(newData);
}
```

Hope that helps (and works didnt have the time to test it). There are a few other ways to do that, using attributes, ids (dont recommend that Id should be unique) and even jQuery data method. Not sure which one is the best but this one is the easiest for me

Comment: o.k.
I am understood the problem before, and now after your explanation I am understanding well. but I trying to separate and stuck on. can you write the correct code or edit my code pls?

Comment: To separate means: to add special field indicating that this is the D or C column.

Comment: You just change this:
"var inputF = $(this).find("input[type=text].changed");"
to this:"var inputC = $(this).find(".C");
        var inputD = $(this).find(".D");"
It will not be a problem with that issue that I want to send only the "changing" (=editing by user) column?

Comment: have you read the second code snippet ? Initially, you wanted to send only the changed value, but you send both fieldValues['c'] and fieldValues['d'] again. Thus I wondered if you want to send only the changed then check for changed class and then add it to fieldValues.